# How can I replace contents of a script element in jsoup without having the new contents encoded?

Tags: java, json, jsoup

#### Background

I have to update the configuration for a jwplayer in a script, which looks like `jwplayer('elem').setup({"filename":"foo/bar.mp4"})`.  I extract the JSON using regex (yeah not the best idea but it's what I've got) then use Gson to parse the JSON, alter what I need to alter, then return a string.

So I'm starting with a string, `newJson`, like `{"filename":"foo/bar.mp4"}`

#### Goal

I want to replace the contents of the script [element](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/index.html?org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html) with the contents of `newJson`:

```
scriptElem.text( "jwplayer('elem').setup(" + newJson + ");" );
```

#### Problem

When the string is inserted into the script, it gets encoded.  [Element.text](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.java#L900) passes string thru the [TextNode constructor](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jsoup/nodes/TextNode.java#L28)- I can't see where the encoding happens here but by the next line the contents of the script elem look like this:

```
jwplayer('elem').setup({&quot;file&quot;:&quot;foo/bar.mp4&quot;});
```

#### Question

**How do I get the JSON back into the script without the quotes being escaped?**

Comment: if i am not mistaken, it depends on how you parse your document in the first place. Could you add the snipet part where you create `Document` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use apache commons for that

```
String newJson = "{&quot;file&quot;:&quot;foo/bar.mp4&quot;}";
String res = "jwplayer('elem').setup(" + newJson + ");";
System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(res));
```

**Result**

```
jwplayer('elem').setup({"file":"foo/bar.mp4"});
```

Download and include `commons-lang-2.4.jar`